# How to find the number of tabs in a file?

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I want to write a shell script that counts a number of tabs used in a given file and then write the result to the file `output.txt`. How to do this?

Comment: i tried using grep $'\t' updates.txt  but i was not able to get what i want

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this:

```
tr -cd '\t' < your_file_with_tabs | wc -c
```

First part (`tr -cd '\t'`) removes everything except for the tabs, second part of pipeline counts characters (which are all tabs).

Thanks @imp25 for the tip about `wc -c`.

Comment: You can do this without the second `tr` if you use `wc -c` to count the characters: `tr -cd '\t' < your_file_with_tabs | wc -c`

Answer (score 1):

```
grep --only-matching input.txt | wc -l > output.txt
```

Example:

```
$ grep --only-matching $'\t' <<< $'\t\t\t\t' | wc -l
4
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
perl -lne '$c += s/\t/\t/g;END{print $c}' file
```

or

```
perl -lne '$c += split /\t+/; $c--;END{print $c}' file
```

or

```
 perl -lne '$c += tr/\t//;END{print $c}' file
```

Comment: You can also use `$c +=()= /\t/g` instead of a substitution, just for variety :-)

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
awk '{t+=gsub(/\t/,x)} END{print t}' file
```